# Negative numbers in numeral system

Tags: number-systems

Is there a numeral system in which numbers can have negative values? If so, what could be the base?
For example (from the head), $34$ represent as $-1, 4, -1$ (read from left to right)

Comment: What is a numeral system and how does your example work?

Comment: I came up with such an example to illustrate, but in real life it does not exist. I mean, for example, that $34$ is represented in the numeral system in base $a$, it is written using negative numbers. What values can the number $a$ take?

Comment: You may be interested in [Balanced ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary) number system and its generalization.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110393/numeral-system-of-base-b?noredirect=1#comment8497982_4110393) that appeared earlier today seems similar.

Answer (score 1):

In the lovely classic *Mathematics Made Difficult* (published in 1971), Carl E. Linderholm notes (on page 63) that we could easily do base-ten arithmetic with the digits $\overline{4},\overline{3},\overline{2},\overline{1},0,1,2,3,4$, and $5$. (Linderhold actually uses upside down $n$'s instead of overlines, but I can't figure out how to TeX that; if someone would like to show me how, I'll gladly change things.) Thus, for example,

$$2\overline{4}5=2\cdot100-4\cdot10+5$$

is a new way of writing $165$, while

$$\overline{1}\overline{2}\overline{3}=-1\cdot100-2\cdot10-3$$

is the new $-123$, so the negative sign itself need never appear. To my knowledge, this system has never quite caught on.